# How to connect filters in two dashboards in one story in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Now I have one story with two dashboards on two page (points). I have same filters for each dashboard on each page. But how can I connect these two filters? It would be better if I choose a value in the filter on first page and the filter on second page will change by itself?

Answer (score 4):

Just as a notice to anyone coming across this post later. There is no current way (current version 2018.2) to apply a filter across story points. Your only option is to use dashboards displayed as tabs with filters applied to all worksheets using related data source or all worksheets using the data source.

This has been a requested feature in Tableau as per their suggested features page since 2015 but has not been implemented.

Comment: For those coming across this answer later, there is also a philosophical reason for there to not be a filter across story points. Stories are meant to be exactly that... a story. Each story point is meant to be unique and independent viewpoint with a premeditated message. If a user wants to utilize the look and feel of a story, they are better off creating UI components in dashboards that look like story points, but navigate instead to other dashboards. Especially on Tableau Server, you can choose to not publish with dashboards as tabs and use buttons for navigation between dashbrds instead.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Bernardo, You can make the filters global, i.e. on the filters tab in your report you can select the column and click on apply to all using the same data source. That should work, but one thing to consider is are there any reports which are using the same data source and are not to be filtered by that filter which you are making global.
If no then the global filter should work,
If yes then you have to select that filter and apply to those specific reports only which you want to filter on Both the dashboard. 
This will make sure that the reports you have selected will be filtered on that column value on both the dashboards.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update. There is still no way (as of version 2019.1.2) to apply a filter across story points.

Answer (score 0):

Make the filters global, or at least to all sheets on each dashboard. From an UX perspective, I would keep the filters on the second story page so the user does not have to go to page one to change a filter.

Comment: "Global filters" apply in "story" does not affect the other dashboards implemented in the other pages of the story